# ASP.NET identify client device

Tags: asp.net

We are building an online ASP.NET time capture system which will be accessed by KIOSKs. The kisoks will be installed in multiple locations.

Some how we need to identify from which Kiosks the request is coming from so that we can can find the Kiosk details from persistent database.

The application will be hosted on internet. Could anyone suggest me how is it possible to identify each Kiosk in stateless?
1. I've already looked at permanent cookies.
2. IP range (could be tricky, given group of kiosk might go via specific firewall).

Any other suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have complete control over the kiosks, then the easiest thing to do would be to add a unique ID of some sort to the [user-agent registry key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#UARegistry). If you don't have complete control, then a permanent cookie might be your only route. If you go with the permanent cookie you could require the client to enter some sort of password/code/id to register the machine before populating the cookie. That would help identify the clients and also prevent unauthorized computers from accessing the system.

Comment: Thanks Rand, is process of setting usr-agent registry key in IPAD same?

Comment: No, the registry key only applies to Windows computers.